# программно запрос привилегий конкретного пользователя windows на c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

есть великолепная функция GetUserName(), которая возвращает имя текущего пользователя к примеру.
Нет ли похожей функции, которая могла бы возвращать , например, группу пользователя
В общем нужно узнать является ли указанный пользователь администратором
Нашёл такую функцию:

```
BOOL IsAppRunningAsAdminMode()
 {
BOOL fIsRunAsAdmin = FALSE;
DWORD dwError = ERROR_SUCCESS;
PSID pAdministratorsGroup = NULL;

// Allocate and initialize a SID of the administrators group.

SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(
    &NtAuthority,
    2,
    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &pAdministratorsGroup))
{
    dwError = GetLastError();
    goto Cleanup;
}

// Determine whether the SID of administrators group is enabled in

// the primary access token of the process.

if (!CheckTokenMembership(NULL, pAdministratorsGroup, &fIsRunAsAdmin))
{
    dwError = GetLastError();
    goto Cleanup;
}
```

Cleanup:
    // Centralized cleanup for all allocated resources.

```
if (pAdministratorsGroup)
{
    FreeSid(pAdministratorsGroup);
    pAdministratorsGroup = NULL;
}

// Throw the error if something failed in the function.

if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwError)
{
    throw dwError;
}

return fIsRunAsAdmin;
```

Возвращает 1, если программа запущена от имени админа и 0, если запущена не от имени админа
Можно ли её как-нибудь применить к другому пользователю системы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл в сборнике win32 api:

```
 #include <windows.h> 
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <lm.h> 
 #pragma hdrstop
bool jerry_coffin_method() 
   { 
      bool result; 
      DWORD rc; 
      wchar_t *user_name = L"Admin1"; 
      USER_INFO_1 *info; 
      DWORD size=4096; 
      rc = NetUserGetInfo( NULL, user_name, 1, (byte **) &info ); 
      ShowMessage(info->usri1_priv); 
      if ( rc != NERR_Success ) 
      return false; 
         }
```

Возвращает 2-ку при наличии прав админа
и 1 из при их отсутствии
user_name - задаём имя пользователя